# Width of controls within horizontal stack panel

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application, I have a horizontal StackPanel that I am trying to use as a toolbar. Within this panel, I have buttons, comboboxes and textboxes. As the buttons are the tallest, the StackPanel takes their height. And the same do the comboboxes and textboxes. But I want them to stay as they are, otherwise they look ugly. How can I prevent them to expand and fill all available space? I tried to set their height to Auto or to an explicit size, but that didn't help. I also tried to replace the StackPanel with a Grid, but this didn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

```
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3, 10">
        <ComboBox x:Name="Agencies" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Value" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgency}"
                  Height="50"  MinWidth="100" Margin="3,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="UploadFile"
            MinWidth="70"
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            attachProperties:ButtonIcon.Icon="Resources/Images/add.png"
            Content="Upload File"  IsEnabled="{Binding EnrollmentFiles.Any}"                           
            Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" />          
         <Button x:Name="EnrollmentDelete"
            MinWidth="70"
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            attachProperties:ButtonIcon.Icon="Resources/Images/Remove.png"
            Content="Delete Enrollment"  IsEnabled="{Binding EnrollmentFiles.Any}"                           
            Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" />

        <TextBox x:Name="WorkSheetName" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `VerticalAlignment` on your `ComboBox` and `TextBox` to something like `Center`. By default it's set to `Stretch`

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" ... />
```